# Laravel Auth checking for users table when i need admins table

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am new to Laravel and i am creating a new SMS (Student Management System) for my first Laravel Project. So, i need 3 tables.

- Admins
- Teachers
- Students

Admins will be me, teachers will be the actual teachers and students will be students. I will have more tables in the futures but i like to keep all the different types of users in their own table. This was simple before laravel. I am in 5.6 and i am using this to login a user:

```
public function auth()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => request(['username']), 'password' => request(['password'])])) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
    }
```

I want to know how i can get the Auth::attempt to check the "admins" table when trying to auth someone in the admins controller. And how do i do this so that way when i am working on the teacher/student authentication, it will check their specific table. I am so confused.

Comment: You can use guards for authentication.  laravel's default guard is `web`  which is configured to use users table. so create different guard and configure it to use admins table and after that you can authenticat an admin like so `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt()`

Comment: Okay. thank you so much for this!

Comment: Hi, i would recommend you use roles and permissions for the different types of users as opposed to storing all users on different tables. Check out the link below on how you would implement such, and then you redirect the users based on their roles.
https://medium.com/@ezp127/laravel-5-4-native-user-authentication-role-authorization-3dbae4049c8a